# Asp.net Dropdown List - Listitem - Resource File - Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, dropdownlistfor

I got a simple Dropdown List, and i wanted to fill this Dropdownlist with Values from a Resource.resx file.

Creating the Resource file and adding the values, each separated by a "," is not the Problem, but to Display each item as selectable Options for the Dropdown.

my html Code Looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDL1">
<asp:ListItem  Text="<%$Resources:DropDown, Abteilungen%>"></asp:ListItem>
```

*Note* Abteilungen is just the Title!

and here is what i am trying to do:

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (string s in Resources.DropDown.Abteilungen.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
                {
                    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s });
                    DDL1.Text = s.ToString();
                }
```

The Result is: The Dropdownlist Shows me only the full values (Value1,Value2,Value3 etc).

But not each Value as selectable item.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine...

- You have 1 records: "Key, Value"
- You split it and s = "Key"
- You assign Text and Value as: Text = s (Text = "Key"), Value = s (Value = "Key")

Instead of it, use this logic:

- You have 1 records: "Key, Value"
- You write it to s variable. In result: s = "Key, Value"
- You split it and assign like: Text = s[0] (Text = "Key"), Value =
  s[1] (Value = "Value")

  ```
  List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (string s in YOUR_COLLECTION)
  {
      string[] keyValue = s.Split(new char[] { ',' })
      items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = keyValue[0], Value = keyValue[1] });
  }
  ```

Comment: Im getting IndexoutofRange exception…  i dont what im doing wrong :(